# Handlebars Form no run Mongodb delete function - typeError gfs.deleteOne

Tags: mongodb, handlebars.js, crud, multer-gridfs-storage

The form below sends images/files to Mongodb using the handlelebars (.hbs) engine and multer-gridfs-storage (Mongodb FIles), **but by clicking delete it generates the following error:**

> TypeError: gfs.deleteOne is not a function

Also, **it does not load the thumbnail of the attached photo**

Ps: I think the error is in HBS form.

Full code :
https://github.com/rebek/upFileHBS

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="custom-file mb-3">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
          <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      </form>
      <hr>

      {{#each files}}
          <div class="card card-body mb-3">
            {{#if file.isImage}}
                <img src="image/{{this.filename}}" alt="">

                {{else}}
                    {{this.filename}}
                <form method="POST" action="/files/{{this._id}}?_method=DELETE">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                </form>
              </div>
          {{/if}}
      {{/each}}

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render('index', { files: false });
    } else {
      files.map(file => {
        if (
          file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ||
          file.contentType === 'image/png'
        ) {
          file.isImage = true;
        } else {
          file.isImage = false;
        }
      });
      res.render('index', { files: files });
    }
  });
});
...
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, GridFSBucket) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err: err });
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Comment: instead of 'gfs.deleteOne' use 'gfs.remove'. Not official answer since .remove is depreciated. I'm using the same code from the Traversy course. Idk how to use deleteOne with this gridstream setup. Was searching how when I found your question.

Comment: Thanks @Renoldus ! Work very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  gfs.files.deleteOne({ filename: req.params.filename}, (err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({ success: false })
            return res.json({ success: true });
        })
```

using the above will delete the file